# How to add dynamic key using ramda map function?

Tags: javascript, key, mapping, ramda.js

I have an array like this :

```
array = ['2020-06-03', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06']
```

An d I want to shape it into this :

```
Object {
  "2020-06-03": Object {
    "selected": true,
    "selectedColor": "#ff5555",
  },
  "2020-06-04": Object {
    "selected": true,
    "selectedColor": "#ff5555",
  },
  "2020-06-05": Object {
    "selected": true,
    "selectedColor": "#ff5555",
  },
}
```

And this how I am doing :

```
const historyDates = map(date => {
      return { selected: true, selectedColor: "#ff5555"};
    }, array);
```

It won't work because where is the key ? how Can I add it using Ramda expressions ?
Also I am returning a map, a new array not an object filled with object.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R.map (as the native `Array.map()`) returns an array. You can generate an array of objects, using the original values as the keys, and then merge them to a single Object:

```js
const { pipe, map, mergeAll } = R

const fn = pipe(
  map(k => ({ [k]: { selected: true, selectedColor: "#ff5555"} })),
  mergeAll
)

const array = ['2020-06-03', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06']

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Another option is to create an array of [key, value], and then convert to an object using R.fromPairs:

```js
const { pipe, map, fromPairs } = R

const fn = pipe(
  map(k => [k, { selected: true, selectedColor: "#ff5555"}]),
  fromPairs
)

const array = ['2020-06-03', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06']

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

With vanilla JS you can use `Array.map()`, and `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = arr => Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(k => [k, { selected: true, selectedColor: "#ff5555"}])
)

const array = ['2020-06-03', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06']

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```